# How do I meet higher level heroes?

Tags: streetpass-quest-find-mii

I have met 11 different Street Pass Miis, and every single one has been a Level 1 Hero in the Find Mii game.

I know that I can get Level 2 Heroes from using Play Coins sometimes, but can I meet higher level heroes through Street Pass or some other means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only natural way would be to meet the same person more then once, the more you meet people the more they will level up.

Comment: Will I be able to use them for the Find Mii game again if that happens?

Comment: Yep, for example.. I live with my sister and every day when we leave our 3DS' at home we get about 2 "tags" from each other. So after the third or fourth day my version of her mii was pretty much at max level. Then whenever I got her again she would be at that level.

Hope that isn't too confusing..

One more thing that I was trying to imply but maybe didn't come off right was that the level always stays.. so no matter what your collected mii's never lose a level.

Comment: Wow. That is a lot of awesome useful information! :)

Answer (score -1):

I figured out when getting wandering cat heroes put the 3d half way up and hold the r button and hire wandering heros (cats) this will mostly get you level 2 heroes.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what you're trying to say. Could you please try and edit your question for both grammar and clarity?

Comment: Without doing anything, I get a level 2 wandering hero about half the time.

Comment: This sounds more like cognitive bias than anything else, like people saying "Hold down A when catching Pokemon". It has no basis in reality, but because they're watching for it they notice it more often.